# How to use index.php?-url with colorbox

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

I got those php-urls like `www.***.com/index.php?task=login`.

My question is how can I use them with [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox)? I'd like to load the content from the login page into my modal popup but I get unexpected results: it shows the complete website inside of the popup. How can I load the content into my modal popup properly when used with such URLs?

Currently my code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".login_link").colorbox({

        href: "<?php echo $setting['site_url'];?>/index.php?task=login",

        onOpen: function(){
            $("#colorbox").css("opacity", 0);
        },
        onComplete: function(){

            var title = 'Login';
            $('#cboxTitle').text(title);
            $("#colorbox").animate({"opacity": 1});
        }
    });
```

Comment: I just wanted to mention that colorbox has problems with the parameters of the URL. It doesn't recognize them.

Comment: If you put http://yoursiteurl/index.php?task=login into your browser address bar, do you see the complete website or just the login section?

Comment: Yes. And I think I figured out the problem but can't solve it. There is a php-file ( misc.inc.php ) which includes parameter-urls like the one above. That file is implemented within another div-tag: <div id="misc_text"><?php include './includes/misc/misc.inc.php';?></div>. What I'd like to do is just load the contents (not the whole site) into my modal-popup with a parameter-url but it loads the whole site. I think I should place <?php include './includes/misc/misc.inc.php';?> into the div cboxLoadedContent but don't know how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now we know that the reason why you see the whole site in the modal is because you are loading the whole site into it (nothing to do with parameters getting ignored), we need to look at how you might load just the component you want.

I assume you are using some kind of CMS framework? This may have a method built in to supply things like this (Joomla for instance allows you to add &tmpl=component to the url and it will magically deliver what you are asking for. I don't know what framework you are using so I cannot advise specifically. This will be the "proper" way to perform the task.

Now assuming the file /includes/misc/misc.inc.php is under your document root, you should be able to invoke it by using something like:

http://your.site.domain/includes/misc/misc.inc.php

as the url. HOWEVER!!!! This is unlikely to work. The chances are that other parts of the framework are instantiated by the calling of index.php, which will not happen if you call the include file directly. Indeed, unlike WordPress, Joomla has measures in place which prevent execution of any of its included files unless they have been invoked via index.php.

Comment: Thank you very much.:) Yes you are right, of course. The CMS I am using is avarcade (that's a special CMS for gaming websites).

Problem is that if the problem is a complex one the guys at avarcade can't help. That's why I was asking it here. My PHP knowledge is very basic so that might be a problem, too.

I will ask again in 2 or 3 weeks again when I have a little bit more experience with PHP and the CMS.